# Regex validate string if it does not contain more than special count of special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm developing a pattern that validates string if it does not contain more then two matches of #. here is code:

```
^[^\!|\@|\$|\%|\^|\&|\*|\+][\w]*([\w ]+\#[\w ]*){0,2}$
```

> [^!|\@|\$|\%|\^|\&|*|+]

this is group of not acceptable symbols.

additionally, the pattern should validate string in case if it contains other symbols( - _ , . / ). each symbol should have it's own counter and should not match in any position more than two times.

for example if i have s string like this:

> Mcloud dr. #33/#45, some text, some text

it should be valid. but in this case should not:

> Mcloud dr. ###33/$#45, ####, ----

What would you suggest ?

Comment: It's a little unclear what you are trying to match. A pair of # or other symbols too ? And post some examples of valid and invalid matches.

Comment: I'd suggest you read a regex tutorial and figure out what `|` does in a character class.

Comment: I tried | and it works but i would like to check each symbol separately.

Comment: Yes [ # , . - _ ] these symbols are acceptable and should have a count checker for each one. for example a pattern should check if string contains # no more than two times, - no more than one time and so on for other symbols and if one of these contain more than it's limit, string should be invalid

Comment: You need to include sample strings in the question. Ones that should match as well as ones that should not match (and why). Don't make people guess what your inputs are. And as melpomene points out, your use of character classes is wrong. Read up on them.

Comment: _and so on for other symbols_ Be clear on that one. And add it to post.

Comment: I added example

Comment: Still unclear on `and so on for other symbols`. Be specific.

Comment: other symbols are: - , . _ ( )

Comment: Okay but how many should each symbol not repeat ? Like `#` should not repeat twice.

Comment: in general no more than two times but it should be manageable.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143079/discussion-between-rahul-and-aleko-gharibashvili).

Answer (score 3):

Given that you want to match **alphanumerics characters** and some special symbols `()-_,./` You have to mention them in a character class like this.

**Regex:** `^(?!.*([(),.#/-])\1)([\w (),.#/-]+)$`

**Explanation:**

`(?!.*([(),.#/-])\1)` asserts that there shouldn't be more than one character mentioned in character class. This asserts from beginning of string to end.

`([\w (),.#/-]+)` matches the rest of the string for allowed characters from beginning to end.

<kbd>**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/b67HVm/3/)**</kbd>

Comment: It's what I looked for, nice one :)